# Angular(V1.5.3) filters

Tags: angularjs, filter, filtering, angular-filters

I'm currently working a page where I want there to be two pieces of information, an array of Sectors which when clicked on a particular sector it will filter the list below it in terms of the projects associated with it.

I'm trying to achieve this by filtering down the items use $filter service in Angular. But for some reason, nothing is happening at all when I click the appropriate sector. It just remains the same.

Here is an image (a very basic layout) just to show you: [Trying to filter a list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olui.png)

I don't have any errors in my console, I think it might be the null value on my controller but I'm not certain, any help would be appreciated.

**Here are my arrays which are in my controller (for now...) along with a public function and scope variable to be used in the html:**

```
$scope.sectors = [
{"id": 0, "name": "Branding", "image": "assets/01_WORK_TILE.jpg"},
{"id": 1, "name": "Retail Design", "image": "assets/WORK_RETAILDESIGN.jpg"},
{"id": 2, "name": "Food & Beverage Design", "image": "assets/WORK_F&B.jpg"},
{"id": 3, "name": "Graphic Communication", "image": "assets/06_WORK_TILE.jpg"},
{"id": 4, "name": "Masterplanning", "image": "assets/WORK_MASTERPLANNING.jpg"},
{"id": 5, "name": "Public Spaces", "image": "assets/WORK_PUBLICSPACES.jpg"},
{"id": 6, "name": "Strategic Insights", "image": "assets/WORK_STRATEGICINSIGHTS.jpg"},
{"id": 7, "name": "Signage & Wayfinding", "image": "./assets/WORK_SIGNAGE&WAYFINDING.jpg"}
```

];

```
$scope.projects = [
{"id": 0, "name": "UK Coffee week", "image": "cw-avatar", "desc": "Using coffee to do good!", "sector": "Branding"},
{"id": 1, "name": "Lexicon", "image": "lexicon-avatar", "desc": "Transforming a Town.", "sector": "Branding"},
{"id": 2, "name": "Ajmal", "image": "ajmal-avatar", "desc": "Fragrance for everyone.", "sector": "Retail Design"},
{"id": 3, "name": "Aelia", "image": "aelia-avatar", "desc": "A World first for travel retail.", "sector": "Retail Design"},
{"id": 4, "name": "Amuse", "image": "amuse-avatar", "desc": "Developing a World of beauty.", "sector": "Retail Design"},
{"id": 5, "name": "Johnnie Walker", "image": "jwalker-avatar", "desc": "A new arrival at Amsterdam Airport.", "sector": "Food & Beverage Design"},
{"id": 6, "name": "Fine Foods", "image": "finefoods-avatar", "desc": "?", "sector": "Graphic Communication"},
{"id": 7, "name": "Nice Duty Free", "image": "nice-avatar", "desc": "?", "sector": "Graphic Communication"},
{"id": 8, "name": "Al Maryah Island", "image": "maryah-avatar", "desc": "?", "sector": "Signage & Wayfinding"},
{"id": 9, "name": "British Land", "image": "britishland-avatar", "desc": "Superior signage and wayfinding.", "sector": "Signage & Wayfinding"}
```

];

```
$scope.currentSector = null;

function setCurrentSector(sector) {
$scope.currentSector = sector;
}

$scope.setCurrentSector = setCurrentSector;
```

**And here is the markup in my view file:**

```
<div layout="column" flex>
    <ul ng-controller="WorkController" ng-repeat="sector in sectors">
        <li style="list-style: none; font-family: portland-bold-font;">
            <a ng-click="setCurrentSector(sector);">{{ sector.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="animation-element slide-up" style="font-size: 0;">
    <p style="height: 25%; text-align: center; background: black; font-family: portland-bold-font; color: white; margin: 0; padding: 0%; font-size: 2.5vw;" ng-cloak>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br /> adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br /> incididunt ut labore et dolore
    </p>
</div>

<div layout="column" style="background:white;">
    <ul ng-controller="WorkController" ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:currentSector.name">
        <li style="list-style: none; font-family: portland-bold-font;">{{ project.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check the value of $scope.currentSector in your 2 ul that defined WorkController. I don't if it's that but generally you declare ng-controller for a complete part of DOM.
I recommend you to encapsulate all DOM into a div and define ng-controller on the head div

Comment: It looks like you're expecting the $filter service to know how to filter your collection.  If that's true, you need to write a custom filter.  Here's a handy article https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/fwXN2YjR84iOfp5wuQO1?p=preview

As I said in comment you declare twice ng-controller in two different parts of dom. In angular controller are not share like service so you had two different controller and your var sector was not "see" by your filter.

I encapsulate DOM into body and declare controller on body :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried to up-vote your answer. Thank you for your help, I injected the controller in the body of the document and it now works. For some reason I thought that you could initialise a piece of the document with ng-controller and it wouldn't affect the rest of it. But obviously that is not the case! Would you mind explaining why it wouldn't work when there was two cases of ng-controller? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can defined a controller where you want in your DOM. BUt the scope of the controller will be restrict to the element and child element which defined the controller. If you defined the controller WorkController in two parts of the dom, angular instantiate 2 instance of WorkController and they work alone.
I edited the plunker to tried to illustrate scope(https://plnkr.co/edit/fwXN2YjR84iOfp5wuQO1?p=preview). I hope this will help you

Comment: I can read angular documentation for controller https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller that explains scope concept and inheritance.

Comment: That makes a whole bunch of sense! Thanks for the explanation and answer I appreciate it Silvinus. As I said I can't up-vote your answer as I haven't got enough rep, but thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the field for filtering:

```
<ul ng-repeat="project in projects | filter: { sector: currentSector.name}">
    <li style="list-style: none; font-family: portland-bold-font;">{{ project.name }}</li>
</ul>
```